# Edit middle button on bottom tab navigation with React-navigation V5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create a Bottom tab navigation with react-navigation V5, like the image below. The middle one with a bigger image size than the others.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some idea from this. I have done using image. You can do by icon as well if you want.
I have change this on focus you can keep it fix.

```
<Tab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                    activeTintColor: 'red',
                   // activeBackgroundColor:'#000',
                    //inactiveBackgroundColor:'red',
                    labelStyle: {
                         position: 'absolute',
                         top: constants.vh(35),
                        fontSize:constants.vh(18),
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Tab.Screen name='Home' //bottom tab for Home
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            let iconName;
                            iconName = focused ? constants.images.bottomHome : constants.images.bottomHome //for icon or image
                            return (
                                <View>
                                    <Image source={iconName} style={{ width: constants.vw(40), height: constants.vh(25) ,position:'absolute',right:constants.vw(-20),bottom:constants.vh(-5)}} resizeMode="contain" />
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                    }}
                    component={HomeScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Share the complete code

Comment: This is complete code. You just need to wrap this code in `return` of a function.

Comment: Is not complete, missing constants variable, iconName etc...